# How to check in app engine if code is executed in transaction?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Simple questions
1. How to check that some of code is executed in transaction?
2. How to get transaction information if it possible?

```
  def someCode():
    class DeleteMe(db.Model):
      pass

    #how to check it here?
    key = db.Key.from_path(DeleteMe.kind(), 'test')
    model = DeleteMe.get(key)
    if model is None:
      model = DeleteMe(key = key)
      model.put()
```

I want to check if someCode() is run in transaction:

```
db.run_in_transaction(someCode)
```

or not:

```
someCode()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `db.is_in_transaction()`

See docs  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#is_in_transaction

If you are starting out, I would suggest you consider looking at ndb, rather than db.
ndb has an equivalent  `ndb.in_transaction()`

You should look at transaction context objects to see what other information you can get/set

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#create_transaction_options